# I'm having trouble with shiny reading my data

Tags: r, shiny, subset, reactive

I'm a bit new to shiny and I've been trying to make an interactive map showing the number of registries collected for a project during one year (start may 2019, end may 2020).

When I run the code the pop-up window opens and display the map and the slider input box like I want, but the map is not showing the data and when I click on each state it displays NA.

When running the code I get this error message:

*Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.yearmon") for "=="Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "==.Date") for "=="Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "==.Date") for "=="Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "==.Date") for "=="Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "==.Date") for "=="Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "==.Date") for "=="Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "==.Date") for "=="*

This is my code:

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Numero de registros"),

    tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                sliderInput("range", "Fecha", 
                            min = as.Date(as.yearmon("2019-05-23")), 
                            max = as.Date(as.yearmon("2020-05-07")), # most recent date on the CSV file. UPDATE with each CSV
                            value = as.Date(as.yearmon("2019-05-23")),
                            timeFormat = "%b %Y",
                )
  )
)

# Shiny app - server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  filteredData <- reactive({
    states <- left_join(states, subset(reg, reg_date == input$range[1]), 
                             by = "id")
    states

  })

  # This reactive expression represents the palette function, which changes as the user makes selections in UI.
  colorpal <- reactive({
    colorFactor(palette = c("#D8F0C6", "#AED68F", "#8ABA64", "#66993E", "#477622", "#274C0A"), reg$Freq)
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # Use leaflet() here, and only include aspects of the map that won't need to change dynamically 
    states <- left_join(states, subset(reg, reg_date ==  as.yearmon("2019-05-23")), by = "id")
    pal <- colorpal()
    leaflet(states) %>% addTiles() %>%
      setView(-102, 23.8, 5)%>% 
      addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                pal = pal, values = ~reg$Freq,
                title = "Registros") %>% 
      addTiles()
  })

  # Incremental changes to the map (in this case, replacing the circles when a new color is chosen) should be performed in   an observer. Each independent set of things that can change should be managed in its own observer.
  observe({
    pal <- colorpal()
    leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(stroke = TRUE, weight = 1, color = "#000000",
                  fillOpacity = 0.8, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                  fillColor = ~pal(Freq), 
                  popup = ~ sprintf("Estado: %s<br/>Registros: %s",
                                    stri_trans_totitle(state_name), 
                                    round(Freq, 1)))
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd really appreciate it someone could help me fix the code.

Comment: is `as.yearmon` from the zoo package? don't you get an error with `as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon("2019-05-23"))`? if so, I'm not sure how your date slider is working. you are also using `==` in `subset` to compare two different data types: `Sys.Date() == zoo::as.yearmon(Sys.Date())` since your `reg_date` appears to be a factor or a date and `input` is a yearmon. I think it would be easiest to format both as character strings, eg, `format(Sys.Date(), '%B %Y') == as.character(zoo::as.yearmon(Sys.Date()))`

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is from the zoo package. But, I think one of the reasons it's not working is that I wasn't grouping the data before entering to the shiny app. I tried using `group.by` by year and it reads the data but still not in the way I wanted (by month and year)